# Where is the JS

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, frontend

Could someone please tell me where the JS is for changing the price when a user clicks on a product custom radio option in the product detail page

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the product custom options, the javascript is in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml`.
I think the `reloadPrice` function is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Goose84, Please tell me where did you find the JS?